# Split, convert to number then join back to string in linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

There are two sql tables from which I want combined data

1. queryTable  --- here queryFrom is number and QueryTo is string of comma separated numbers

[image]

2. userTable

[image]

I am able get data for queryFrom where there is single user but not for queryTo, I want to split the string {","}, convert to int array, search in userTable for that number and join back with respective username.

here is my query

```
 var query = (from q in queryTable
              select {
              Id  = q.id,
              QueryFrom = userTable.where(u=> u.id == q.queryFrom).select(s=>s.userName),
              QueryTo = q.queryTo // split and join logic here
              }).ToList();
```

Current output ---

[image]

expected output ---

[image]

Comment: We'd rather class definitions with real C# code to load the data.

Comment: And we'd rather real code. Your question is rather average.

Comment: You should change your "queryTable" into a table that has `QueryTo` as int, and records like [1,1], [1,3], [2,3], [3,1], [3,2]. Otherwise any form of querying is an enormous hassle.

Answer (score 1):

i have tested with this piece of code:

1. classes defintion

---

```
public class queryTable
{
    public queryTable(int queryId, int queryFrom, string queryto)
    {
        QueryId = queryId;
        QueryFrom = queryFrom;
        Queryto = queryto;
    }

    public int QueryId { get; set; }
    public int QueryFrom { get; set; }
    public string Queryto { get; set; }
}
public class userTable
{
    public userTable(int userId, string userName)
    {
        UserId = userId;
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
var queryTable = new List<queryTable> { new queryTable(1, 1, "2,3"), new queryTable(2, 2, "3"), new queryTable(3, 3, "1,2") };
var userTable = new List<userTable> { new userTable(1, "Tom"), new userTable(2, "Mike"), new userTable(3, "Harry") };

var query = 
(from q in queryTable
    select (new {
    Id = q.QueryId,
    QueryFrom = userTable.Where(u => u.UserId == q.QueryId).Select(s => s.UserName).FirstOrDefault(),
    QueryTo = string.Join(",", q.Queryto.Split(',')   //split
                                .Select(n => userTable.Where(u => u.UserId == int.Parse(n.Trim())) 
                                .Select(u => u.UserName).FirstOrDefault())
                         )
                })).ToList();
foreach (var l in query)
    Console.WriteLine(l);
```

result:

```
{ Id = 1, QueryFrom = Tom, QueryTo = Mike,Harry }
{ Id = 2, QueryFrom = Mike, QueryTo = Harry }
{ Id = 3, QueryFrom = Harry, QueryTo = Tom,Mike }
```

following the error you have: try to compare string and not int

```
.Select(n => userTable.Where(u => u.UserId.toString() == n.Trim())
```

Comment: "The LINQ expression 'DbSet<User>()\r\n    .Where(u0 => u0.Id == long.Parse(n))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."  

Got this error

Comment: try to add list at the end .Select(n => userTable.Where(u => u.UserId == int.Parse(n.Trim())).ToList()

Comment: ToList(), ToArray(), AsEnumerable(), AsQueryable(), tried all of this.... nothing works...

gives this error

"Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DB.Core.Entities.User]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DB.Core.Entities.User]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String] Select[User,String](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DB.Core.Entities.User], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[DB.Core.Entities.User,System.String]])' (Parameter 'arg0')"

Comment: @dev99 - This is still the issue with bringing this into memory.

Comment: try to compare string and not int see my answer modified

Comment: tried that doesn't work..
@Enigmativity how can I bring this to memory.. please share more info

Comment: @dev99 - How did you try to bring it into memory? It'll work when you do.

Answer (score 1):

Given your data:

```
var userTable = new[]
{
    new { UserId = 1, UserName = "Tom" },
    new { UserId = 2, UserName = "Mike" },
    new { UserId = 3, UserName = "Harry" },
};

var queryTable = new[]
{
    new { QueryId = 1, QueryFrom = 1, QueryTo = "2, 3" },
    new { QueryId = 2, QueryFrom = 2, QueryTo = "3" },
    new { QueryId = 2, QueryFrom = 3, QueryTo = "1, 2" },
};
```

Here is the cleanest way I can think of doing this:

```
var query =
(
    from q in queryTable
    join uf in userTable on q.QueryFrom equals uf.UserId
    let uts =
        from qt in q.QueryTo.Split(',')
        join ut in userTable on int.Parse(qt.Trim()) equals ut.UserId
        select ut.UserName
    select new
    {
        q.QueryId,
        QueryFrom  = uf.UserName,
        QueryTo = String.Join(", ", uts),
    }
).ToList();
```

That gives me:

[image: query]

Comment: "Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet<User>()' by 'RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in Entity Framework. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information."  

Got this error

Comment: Splitting the commas and trimming the strings has to happen in memory. You need to bring the data in to memory first. Then this will work.

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty here is because it's an invalid database design. Columns should have single values, not a list of values, and this example shows why. If you replace the existing multi-valued QueryTo column with separate rows, with integer columns QueryFrom and QueryTo, the data manipulation becomes trivial.

Query table: QueryId int, QueryFrom int
QueryTo table: QueryId int, QueryTo int (one row for each user being queried)

Comment: sorry but I can't map single queryTo int one row for each user because it will make my table fill with unnecessary duplicate data of other columns as I have more columns in queryTable than mentioned here.

Comment: @dev99 - No, you'd change the database design to prevent duplicates too.